# How to use form with class form-group, form-horizontal

Tags: html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap

[image]

The page captured in the image above contain a container 4 rows, etc.
I can describe it's structure like:
...

```
<div class="container">
  <h:form>
    <div class="row"> <!--row1-->
      ...
    </div>
    <div class="row"> <!--row2-->
      ...
    </div>
    <div class="row"> <!--row3-->
      ...
    </div>
    <div class="row"> <!--row4-->
      ...
    </div>
  </h:form>
</div>
```

**The question is:** How can I make it look like this:
[image]

I think I should use 
h:form class="form-horizontal" and h:form class="form-group"

If I style my page like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <h:form class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="row form-group"> <!--row1-->
          ...
    </div>
            <div class="row form-group"> <!--row1-->
          ...
    </div>
    <div class="row"> <!--row3-->
      ...
    </div>
    <div class="row"> <!--row4-->
      ...
    </div>
  </h:form>
</div>
```

the first 2 rows look like this:
[image]

and if I style the page like this:

```
<div class="container">
   <h:form class="form-horizontal">
      <div class="row form-group">
          <div class="col-sm-1">
             ...
             <!--inputText-->
           </div>
          <div class="col-sm-1">
             ...
             <!--inputText-->
           </div>
          <div class="col-sm-1">
             ...
             <!--inputText-->
           </div>
          <div class="col-sm-1">
             ...
             <!--inputText-->
           </div>
          <div class="col-sm-1">
             ...
             <!--commandButton-->
           </div>
           <div class="col-sm-7"></div>
       </div>
       <div class="row form-group">
       <div class="col-sm-1 col-sm-offset-3">
          <div class="col-sm-1">
             ...
             <!--inputText-->
           </div>
          <div class="col-sm-1">
             ...
             <!--commandButton-->
           </div>
           <div class="col-sm-7"></div>
       </div>
   </h:form>
</div>
```

the first 2 rows looks like:
[image]

, and if I style the page with the structure above but with columns of 2 units:

```
<div class="col-sm-2">
```

the rows are not good:
[image]

Comment: You can't nest h:form that's not valid in HTML.

Comment: https://validator.w3.org should have hinted that nesting forms is illegal.

Answer (score 0):

As Balus and I said before you can't nest h:form because that is invalid in HTML. For that reason your buttons on the rows 3, 4 aren't working. You need to separate each h:form so it can work. Anyway, I'm gonna help you with the first form and this will give an insight of how you could do the other forms.
If you use the form-horizontal you don't need to use the row class. Before using this snippet you need to set the value attribute I left it so because I don't know how your backing bean is. I suggest you to read about bootstrap grid system to help you to do the other forms. http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/

```
    <div class="container">
     <h:form styleClass="form-horizontal">    
        <div class="form-group">
           <div class="col-md-2">
             <h:inputText value="#" />
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-2">
             <h:inputText value="#" />
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-2">
             <h:inputText value="#" />
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-2">
              <h:inputText value="#" />
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-4">
              <h:commandLink value="Add" />
           </div>
       </div>
     </h:form>
    </div>
```

Comment: It looks bad. Please take a look at my examples.

Comment: It doesn't look so bad. Look at my fiddler: http://codepen.io/rrlpl/pen/jqJbXz
You need to check the css style that are being applied to the elements and if you want them closer may want to reduce the padding or marging to those inputs. If you want that I continue helping please provide  a functional fiddler.

Answer (score -1):

Roberto is right. You shouldn't use nested element there.Here is a clean example from bootstrap you may use

```
 <form class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="form-group">
<label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
 <div class="col-sm-10">
  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-    label">Password</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
   <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3"      placeholder="Password">
</div>
</div>
 <div class="form-group">
<div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox"> Remember me
    </label>
  </div>
   </div>
 </div>
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign in</button>
  </div>
   </div>
   </form>
```